# Word request for scenario "where everything is a lie" like disillusionment?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am looking for a word like disillusionment. Like the movie The Usual Suspect, suppose, you have a friend, who has been telling you a story.

You believe the story, and than you suddenly realize that everything he told you is a lie.(Gaslighting)

You might lose your sanity, and start questioning everything.

What would be the best word to describe it?

For e.g.

"Jon has been fooling his friend Jane. But Jane does not know it. Jane believes everything Jon tells him. Jon leaves. Suddenly one day, Jan realizes that everything Jon told him is a lie, and she has been fooled. Jan slowly loses her sanity, and starts questioning even her real experiences."

Does disillusionment describe this scenario? She has gone insane/is disillusioned? etc.

If yes, what other words can I use?

Comment: Could you add an example sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: @cigien  edited.

Comment: Thanks, but that's only clarification of what the word should mean (which is good). I meant something more like a "fill in the blank" example sentence, where you want to use the word.

Comment: Perhaps "to have a mental break" or "to go mad" or "to become unreasonably paranoid"... I'm not sure there is a singular word for this scenario.